# AWS RDS: Can't get modify of Instance Class to go through

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In the AWS RDS Console using an IAM user with full permission, I selected our current RDS instance which is a db.t1.micro, clicked on "Instance Actions" and chose "Modify". I then changed both the MySQL version to 5.6.37 (current version is 5.6.34) and the Instance Class to db.t2.small. I also checked the "Apply Immediately" checkbox, and applied the modification. However, the modification didn't happen.

Instead, I'm seeing the following in the Maintenance Details for the instance:

```
Maintenance Window: sat:20:00-sat:20:30
Pending Modifications: DB Instance Class: db.t2.small, Engine Version: 5.6.37  
Pending Maintenance: None
```

I figured maybe the "Apply Immediately" didn't go through, so I decided to just wait for the Maintenance window this Saturday. However, nothing happened on Saturday, and the situation remains the same.

This morning I tried using "Modify Instance" again and made sure I for sure selected the "Apply Immediately", but the result is the same.

I also tried to use the command-line interface to upgrade the instance with this command:

```
aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier xxxxx --db-instance-class db.t2.small --apply-immediately
```

But this gives the following error (perhaps a hint?):

```
Service rds not available in region US West (Oregon)
```

The instance I tried to modify is in the US West (Oregon) region.

Any help is appreciated. I'm willing to use a different method to upgrade the instance, but I'm hoping to avoid having to change all the DB address and login settings on our websites and applications.

Comment: what is your *awscli* version?

Comment: aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/4.4.0-43-Microsoft

Comment: That sounds like a pretty old version of aws-cli.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely the case. I can't remember where this version came from. I'm using the Windows 10 "Bash on Ubuntu" and somehow got that version, perhaps with apt-get? Either way, I've managed to get the latest version with pip and will use that in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by stopping the instance with a saved snapshot and then started it again. This cleared out the "Pending Maintenance" but did not actually perform the upgrade. I then went through the "Modify" action again but only chose to modify the instance class. This time the modify happened right away and now it's the correct instance class.